# Why can I not use autofit on shapes?

Tags: google-drawings

I'd like to have the shapes resize with text. There seems to be an option to accomplish this, but it's greyed out. How can I enable autofit for my shapes?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was using 'shapes' for my text, not Text boxes, which can indeed be set to autofix by the settings mentioned above.